# npm equivalent of `pip install -r requirements.txt`

Tags: npm, pip

What are the npm equivalent of:

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Comment: Usually `npm install` is all you need. The requirements are generally in the `package.json`, not in `requirements.txt`.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Normally dependencies in a node project are installed via package.json: https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json

You install each dependency with `npm install --save my-dependency` and it will be added to the package.json file. So the next person on the project can install all the dependencies with `npm install` command on the same folder of package.json.

But in my case i wanted to install global requirements of npm via a text file (similar to `pip install -r requirements.txt`).

You can do that with:

`cat requirements.txt | xargs npm install -g`

Answer (score 12):

You might want to take a look at the documentation for [npm shrinkwrap](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/shrinkwrap). It creates an `npm-shrinkwrap.json`, which will take precedence over any `package.json` when installing.

Basically, the equivalent is:

```
npm shrinkwrap
npm install
```

**Edit:**

Since v5.0.0, npm now always creates a [`package-lock.json`](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package-lock.json), with the same format as `npm-shrinkwrap.json`. There have been other changes since then, not least in the latest v5.6.0. See the [package-lock docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package-lock.json).

Comment: Also note that npm has a feature that pip doesn't - appending to the list of dep's as they are installed. Use `npm install --save aPackage` (or `npm install --save-dev aDevPackage`).

Answer (score 7):

To install npm packages globally from a text file (e.g. `npm-requirements.txt`) with a format similar to a pip requirement file:

```
sed 's/#.*//' npm-requirements.txt | xargs npm install -g
```

This allows comments in the requirements file, just like pip. ([source](https://www.monolune.com/installing-global-npm-packages-from-a-requirements-file/))

A command similar to `pip freeze > requirements.txt` is:

```
ls "$(npm root -g)" > npm-requirements.txt
```

However, this is imperfect because it does not save the version numbers of npm packages.