# gem equivalent of `pip install -r requirements.txt`

Tags: rubygems

I made similar question for npm here: [npm equivalent of `pip install -r requirements.txt`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11840341/npm-equivalent-of-pip-install-r-requirements-txt)

This is for gem.

What are the gem equivalent of:

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There isn't a direct comparison in Ruby, but we have something very similar. Look at the [bundler gem](https://bundler.io/) for how to write your list of required gems into a Gemfile and automatically generate a Gemfile.lock which contains the current versions installed.

Comment: Question was to have equivalent of pip freeze... In translation from python ecosystem: how to create Gemfile (or Gemfile.lock) for current gem environment (all packages in current `gem env`). I did not find way how to use bundler to transform `gem list` into something what can be used with `gem install ...`

Answer (score 2):

My solution is:

```
serverA: $ gem list | tr -s ',[ ()]' ' ' | awk '$2 ~ /[0-9]\.[0-9]/ {print $1" -v "$2; next} $3 ~ /[0-9]\.[0-9]/ {print $1" -v "$3}' > reqs.txt

serverB: $ cat reqs.txt | while read  l; do echo "=== Installing 'gem install $l' ===";  gem install $l --conservative || exit 1; done
```

My situation was. On server "A" I have 3rd party developed ruby scripts with many dependencies and no Gemfile. I have to use those same ruby scripts on server "B". How can I easily "copy" ruby env with all possibly required gems to server "B" (same versions).